# Appgyver/Phonegap w/ AngularJS: Sending raw audio data to the AT&T Speech API

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cordova

I am working on an Appgyver app using AngularJS and have been trying to integrate voice control using the AT&T Speech to Text API, but I've been having trouble figuring out how to send audio data across the web.

My course of action thus far has been to use the Phonegap `Media` object to create a temporary audio file, record to it, and then send that file. Everything works fine up until attempting to send the file. I've tried several different methods of transporting the file, including Phonegap's `FileTransfer` object, `$.ajax`, and even Angular's `$http` service, but nothing has worked thus far.

After talking with the folks over at AT&T, it seems that the Phonegap `FileTransfer` object won't work because it encapsulates the data with MIME boundaries, and the API is expecting raw data. I've tried using a `FileReader` object to extract the data using `readAsDataURL()` as well. This was the code from my most recent attempt:

```
$scope.getOptions = (size) ->
  {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + $scope.access_token
    'Content-Type': 'audio/wav'
    'X-SpeechContext': 'Generic'
    'X-arg': 'ClientApp=MyApp'
    'Content-Length': size
  }

$scope.getFile = (file) ->
  options = $scope.getOptions(file.size)
  url = 'https://api.att.com/speech/v3/speechToText'
  fr = new FileReader()

  fr.onloadend = (evt) ->
    $.ajax url, {
      headers: options
      contentType: false
      data: evt.target.result
      error: (xhr, status, error) ->
        alert status
        alert error
      success: (data, status, xhr) ->
        alert status
      type: 'POST'
    }

  fr.readAsDataURL(file)
```

However, only the error function was triggered, with no error message being returned. When I instead added the returned data from the `FileReader` to a `FormData` object, the request went through, but again, the data was not in the format that the AT&T API was expecting.

If there is anyone who can help me figure out where I went wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.